# Remove a specific query parameter from URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, redirect

I have a URL such as:

```
http://www.example.com/something?abc=one&def=two&unwanted=three
```

I want to remove the URL parameter unwanted and keep the rest of the URL in tact and it should look like:

```
http://www.example.com/something?abc=one&def=two
```

This specific parameter can be anywhere in the URL with respect to other parameters.

The question looks very simple, but I tried many times but failed in the end.

Answer (score 2):

The entire query string is present in the `$args` variable or at the end of the `$request_uri` variable. You will need to construct a regular expression to capture everything before and after the part you wish to delete.

For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(/something\?.*)\bunwanted=[^&]*&?(.*)$ ) 
{
    return 301 $1$2; 
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for more, and [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.