# Removing only a specific URL parameter in Nginx with rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make Nginx remove only a specific parameter from the requested URL. Let's say that the parameter name is `par2`. Here are the examples of requested URLs:

```
www.example.com/page?par1=a&par2=b
www.example.com/page?par2=b
```

Those pages should redirect to:

```
www.example.com/page?par1=a
www.example.com/page
```

Here is what I have in conf file at the moment:

```
location / {
    ...
    if ($args ~* "par2") {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $request_uri permanent;
    }
}
```

This partly works - it does remove `par2` parameter, but it removes all of the other parameters as well and redirects to:

```
www.example.com/page
www.example.com/page
```

How to make it remove only a specific parameter (`par2` in this case)?

EDIT:
As far as I know, it's recommended to use `if` only if it's followed by `rewrite`, so I'd prefer such a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a specific query parameter from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571564/remove-a-specific-query-parameter-from-url)

Comment: @RichardSmith There is no accepted answer in that question and, as far as I know, it's recommended to use `if` only if it's followed by `rewrite`, so I'd prefer such a solution. Unfortunately, it's possible that there is no such solution.

Comment: Yeah, not all of my answers are accepted by the questioner. But, Nginx's [own documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) recommends `rewrite...last` or `return...`, for an `if` within a `location` block.

Comment: OK, then I might try it, but what would the regex code be like? This parameter can be anywhere, there's no `something` in the path, like in that other question. `^(.*)\bpar2=[^&]*&?(.*)$ )`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your use case when parameter can be anywhere

```
location /page {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^(/page)(.par2=[0-9a-zA-Z]&?)$){
       return 302 $1;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~ ^(/page\?.+)(.par2=[0-9a-zA-Z])(.*)$){
       return 302 $1$3;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~ ^(/page\?)(par2=[0-9a-zA-Z]&?)(.+)$){
       return 302 $1$3;
    }
}
```